# Kotlin abstract method with body

Tags: interface, kotlin, abstract

As mention [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html#resolving-overriding-conflicts): if a function in an interface has no body it is abstract  by default. But there is nothing about interface's function with body.

Example:

```
interface MyInterface {
    fun foo() { print("Something") }
    fun bar()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(MyInterface::foo.javaMethod)
    println(MyInterface::bar.javaMethod)
}
```

Output will be:

```
public abstract void MyInterface.foo()
public abstract void MyInterface.bar()
```

How it's possible, that method with defined body is abstract?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has to do with the way default methods in Kotlin interfaces are implemented. The `foo` and `bar` methods in your interface really are both abstract.

However, there is an inner class inside the interface that looks something like this (simplified):

```
public interface MyInterface {
   void foo();
   void bar();

   public static final class DefaultImpls {
      public static void foo() {
         System.out.print("Something");
      }
   }
}
```

This class is the one that contains the default implementations of any functions that you gave a body to inside the interface.

Then, if you create a class that implements this interface, and you don't override the `foo` method:

```
class MyClass: MyInterface {
    override fun bar() {
        println("MyClass")
    }
}
```

Then you get one generated automatically, which just calls the implementation inside `DefaultImpls`:

```
public final class MyClass implements MyInterface {
   public void bar() {
      System.out.println("MyClass");
   }
   public void foo() {
      MyInterface.DefaultImpls.foo();
   }
}
```

---

You can find all these details by using the bytecode viewer that comes with the Kotlin plugin (`Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin Bytecode`, and then the `Decompile` option).

Comment: Is it true even if the compiler targets Java 8? Does it define foo() as a default method in that case?

Comment: A lot of books about OOP writes that abstract method is a method that is declared, but contains no implementation. Thanks for explanation!

Comment: As far as I can tell, the same inner class solution is used with the Java 8 target as well. Look at it with both the built-in decompiler as well as JD-GUI.

Comment: Thank you @zsmb13

Comment: Thank you @hotkey